# Is Azure Application ID considered a secret token

Tags: azure-active-directory

I know that it is not a secure practice to have any secret tokens in configuration files, however I have been unable to find out if the application ID is considered a secret. Would having the app ID in config.json be acceptable or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Azure App ID is not considered to be a secret. In case of native apps and web apps, the Azure App ID is quite visible, as a URI parameter, to the client in the browser redirect during authn/authz.

Answer (score 0):

I would point out that it's the same as a login. Is login a secret? No, but it's a combination with a password that opens the door.

Let's say you are using Service Principal for some internal stuff (basically a service account) the AppID is nowhere to be visible to outsiders. By making it publicly known you have simplified the job for an attacker because now he only has to guess the secret (provided you are not using certificate auth).